# How does one have buttons to do different things from the same view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have three buttons made with interface builder in the same view of my app. I want each button to do separate IBActions, but when I try to do

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
if([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus] == NotReachable) {
    [self.textfield resignFirstResponder];
    self.translation.text = @"Sorry, you need an internet connection to translate.";
}
else {
    // Connected to the internet
    [self.textfield resignFirstResponder];
    NSString *toTranslate = self.textfield.text;
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?keyword=%@", toTranslate];
    NSURL *translationUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSData *translationHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:translationUrl];
    TFHpple *translationParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:translationHtmlData];
    NSString *translationXpathQueryString = @"/html/body/pre";
    NSArray *translationOutput = [translationParser searchWithXPathQuery:translationXpathQueryString];
    NSString *translatedString = ((TFHppleElement *)translationOutput[0]).firstChild.content;
    self.translation.text = translatedString;
}
}
```

it gives a "method definition for 'button' not found" warning on the `@implementation` of the viewcontroller.m.

What am I doing wrong with this method or is there a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its an interface builder issue, try re-connecting the method from IB

Comment: sorry, rather new at this, but how?

Comment: go to the connections tab and press the x next to the method to remove it and than re-connect it like usual.